# 10ns squarewave single pulse circuit

Tags: circuit-design, pulse

- I'm trying to design a `10ns` pulse circuit that will generate a square wave, and pulse once when its triggered.
- It will be triggered by a push-button.
- It should be capable of running directly from a `100 watt` `DC 24V` PSU.

I'm using this circuit as a part of a EMP. If anyone could kindly assist me in how to go about designing it, and providing a detailed diagram required make it, it would be more appreciated. [image: Link to the scheme I made]

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: _"spark gap with supercapacitors"_ `\_(^^)_/` , what Prateek mean't to say was, what you done so far regarding designing the circuit? Do you have some schematic? Would like to include it in your original post so that people can share their input. The thing is nobody would like to do everything for you. If they see you made an effort, they will come forward and help you with your design for sure.

Comment: What voltage and current do you expect from the pulse? Do you have a specification on rise and fall time?

Comment: @DuckDodgers I have made a scheme but I don't think it works, I will add the link now

Comment: Make sure to familiarize yourself with the local laws for firing off EMP's.
Worst case is a prison sentence or a very very hefty fine.

Comment: You can't use a common 555 to get a pulse as narrow as 10ns nor can you operate it at 24V. This is not a trivial task but you need to provide much more information about your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might be to start with a 100 MHz oscillator, a dual flip flop, and an AND gate as shown below.  There are other combinations of flip flops and logic that will do the job.  You will have to make sure you de-bounce the switch and watch your layout carefully.  You'll probably want ECL parts to keep your pulses square, otherwise you will have rise and fall times in the 2 nS range and your pulse will be more analog-looking.  ECL parts are a 5-10 bucks apiece.  Most "D" flip flops have both Q and /Q outputs, so you wouldn't need the inverter, but you are still probably going to spend $15 for the two parts, plus you oscillator.  Of course as @elliotanderson mentions, this is logic level, so you will need to generate logic level voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJPWhU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Good Luck!

Comment: I think a latching debounce circuit would be in order here if repeated pulses are not allowed.  A set and reset button that will send the single one cycle pulse out when the debounce is set OR reset.  If you just want the set input to generate a pulse you will have to have some additional careful gating to prevent any spurious edges getting through.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not easy to find a monostable multivibrator IC that will give you a 10 ns pulse. Want you want to do is purposefully synthesize a glitch. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzeEMv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1, R2, and C2 debounce the switch. Using a Schmitt trigger inverter will help with debouncing as well. The inverter drives a window comparator that generates a pulse whose width is given by R4*C3 - R3*C2. Use a dual comparator to give yourself the best chance of matching offsets, gain, propagation delays, slew rates, etc. It's going to be easier to do this at lower voltage (VCC = 5 V), which should give you small and tight propagation delays. It might take some work to translate the output to 24 V at these speeds, but definitely not impossible.

Comment: Is there a specific comparator I need or any will do?

Comment: and also that is it possible to simply use a transformer to step up the voltage?

Comment: You'll need a fast comparator like a TLV3502. Say the dual comparator has a 1% mismatch in propagation delay. If the nominal delay is 5 us, the mismatch is 50 ns (which can completely eliminate your 10 ns pulse), but if the nominal delay is 5 ns, the mismatch is only 50 ps, and your pulse should still come through just fine. A pulse transformer could work. You may have some difficulty buying one off the shelf that meets your specific requirements, but I haven't looked so you may get lucky. A normal (power) transformer will not work, of course.

Comment: Will a  LT®1715 comparator works.    Datasheet:https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1715fa.pdf

Comment: @RickyHu Sure, that looks fine. However, this is a fairly sensitive circuit and will require some prototyping and experimenting to get right. You should reduce the value of one of the resistors and put a pot in series so you can play around a bit and find what works.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution beside a pulse transformer as I couldn't find any at all with the specific requirements, thanks